# How to get outer part of the mesh?

Tags: selection-tools

I have a mesh which has a clear outer structure but is pretty complicated "inside":

[image: Clear outer mesh]
[image: Weird and complicated inside]

How can I separate ONLY the outside part? Is there any better way than selecting the vertices manually in edit mode?

Comment: I guess not, but you could try to see the mesh in edit mode (solid, with "limit selection to visible" enabled) from front view, and there "select"  all the visible vertices. Then repeat from "back", "top", "bottom", "left" and "right" views. Then "hide" all selected vertices. You could just be left with "invisible from outside" vertices... that you can then use (delete would be complicated)... result could depend from the model inside structure, but it could also be simpler than doing all by hand... :D

Answer (score 2):

Are they two separate chunks of mesh? It looks like they are from the images.

If so select only one vertex from the outer shell, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to *Select All Linked* and it should select all the outer part.

Alternatively in Edit Mode select all faces, press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Loose parts* and it should break your object apart by all separate chunks.

If they are not separate chunks then I'm afraid you don't really have a chioce other than manually selecting everything.

Under Edit Mode you can enable the option *Limit selection to Visible* in the 3DView header button, and use regular selection methods to select only the visible parts of the mesh. With some luck the 'inner' parts are occluded and wont be selected.